# The lifespan of bugs

Tags: halacha

The Gemara in Chulin  (58b) days that any creature that doesn't have bones can not live for more than a year. This fact has alot of ramifications for the halachos of bugs in foods and it is relied on as if it is a non disputed fact. Does anybody know if this idea is accepted by the scientists of today or if there is a different understanding of the Gemara that would make it fit with what we know today?

Comment: Contact Nathan Slifkin,thats his area of expertise

Comment: @sam, I tried that before I tried this site. He's still formulating an answer and hasn't responded yet so I figured this would be a good forum to try to get some clarity.

Comment: what are the 'ramifications for halachos of bugs in foods'? 'Relied on' for what?